# How do I unset "!::" environmental variable in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a build script that is failing because it tries to `unset` an environmental variable called `!::`. That fails:

```
$ unset -v '!::'
sh: unset: `!::': not a valid identifier
```

How do I unset that variable? This is on Windows by the way (MSYS).

Answer (score 2):

Aha, I found the answer:

```
env --unset='!::'
```